# Adding an additional include directory for VS10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, directory, cuda, include-path, project-settings

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to add another directory for a single project. On a regular C/C++ project I'm allowed the option of navigating to the directory, but here I have to enter the directory myself, but this is a CUDA c/C++ project. My question is how would I add lets just say: `C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CUDA Programs\common` as an include directory.

[image: A screen grab of my project]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to paste the path into the include directories list. You can separate paths with a semicolon.

```
c:\foo\baa;c:\program files\blah\blah;c:\whatever
```

In earlier versions of the build rules, the include directory did not seem to be added correctly if it ended in a backslash, or if it was wrapped in quotes, so try and avoid either of those.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer you question [VS10 "Additional Include Directories" Point to VS9 Includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526753/vs10-additional-include-directories-point-to-vs9-includes)

Comment: No, bear in mind that this isn't VC this is CUDA C, and I'm using a .cu file.